# Stop computing when Metal kernel output buffer is full?

Tags: ios, kernel, metal

I have a metal compute kernel that takes input points from a buffer `particles`, and populates a new buffer `particlesOut`. My compute kernel is defined as:

```
kernel void compute(device DrawingPoint *particles [[buffer(0)]],
                device Particle *particlesOut [[buffer(1)]],
                constant ComputeParameters *params [[buffer(2)]],
                device atomic_int &counter [[buffer(3)]],
                uint id [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
```

This works fine, so long as the output buffer has room for the number of records populated.

So, for instance, if the input buffer has 10,000 records, and for each of those records I create 10 output records, and the output buffer has a length of 100,000, then all is fine. In other words, if the number of output records is fixed and is large enough, all is fine.

But for some input records, I would like a random number of output records to be populated. For instance, some I would like to populate 5, and another I would like to create 200 (and any number in-between).

I am using an `atomic_int` for the output record's position in the buffer. Again, this works if I have a fixed number of records populated per input record.

I am populating the output buffer like this:

```
//Output buffer is 10 times the size of the input buffer
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    int counterValue = atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    ...
    particlesOut[counterValue].position = finalPoint;
}
```

This works fine.

If I try to make it work on a variable number instead of the fixed value, the buffer is way under populated (instead of getting say 100,000 particles populated, maybe only 10,000 are populated).

For example:

```
int numberOfOutputPoints = someRandomValueBetweenFiveAndTwoHundred();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOutputPoints; i++) {
    int counterValue = atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);

     //particleCount is the size of the output buffer
     if (counterValue > params->particleCount) {                   
         return;
     }

    ...
    particlesOut[counterValue].position = finalPoint;
}
```

When I do that, only a small number of the particles in the output buffer are actually populated.

I looked at using different options for `atomic_fetch_add_explicit`, but only `memory_order_relaxed` will compile.

I tried using:

```
int counterValue = atomic_fetch_add(&counter, 1)
```

But, the compiler reports that there is no matching function. Other than having the buffer output large enough for every record to populate the maximum number of possible particles populated (e.g. 200 times 10,000), is there any way to make it dynamic?

In other words, I just want to stop populating the output buffer when it is full.

Comment: Did you clear buffer 3 (the one bound to the `counter` parameter) to 0 before dispatching the compute kernel? Also, are you sure your `someRandomValueBetweenFiveAndTwoHundred()` is actually producing values with the distribution you expect? If it's also returning a small number, you'd get fewer outputs than you expect.

Comment: Correct, I am clearing the counter to 0 at the beginning of each cycle. I'm actually not using a random number yet, but like if the output buffer is 10x the size of the input and I use any value larger than 10 for the for loop the issue happens (e.g. 20).

Comment: So it turns out I was passing the wrong number to `params->particleCount` - my apologies! If I set the for loop to 20 instead of 10 now, half of the points are populated in the output buffer for each input point (eg each gets 10 instead of 20). I was hoping to have them filled in order, but since the operation is concurrent, I guess there is no way to do that without using a fixed size for the number of input points?

Comment: You could atomically increment by `numberOfOutputPoints` outside of the loop and then use `counterValue + i` inside the loop. There's still a race among the threads as to their overall order (and which get prevented from outputting at all), but each thread's outputs will all be together.

Comment: Interesting, but I am afraid that it isn't clear to me how that would work. If `numberOfOutputPoints` is set to 0 for the beginning of each pass, then the for the first input particle the number would be 1 and only one record in the output buffer would be populated (and drawn for that frame), then 2 for the next input particle and so on. Could you possibly show a simple example (pseudo code is fine) and I would be happy to rephrase my question and possibly accept your answer.

Comment: `numberOfOutputPoints` would not be the atomic variable, it would be the amount that a given thread reserves for itself in the output buffer. You said it would be between 5 and 200. When/why would it be 0? Your code currently reserves `numberOfOutputPoints` indirectly, by reserving 1 each time through the loop. I'm suggesting reserve them all at once before the loop.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks for clarifying! I thought you were suggesting to make `numberOfOutputPoints` an atomic variable. I'll give that a shot. Thanks again!